# Problemas con Spring "The injection point has the following annotations"

Tags: java, spring

Buen día!!! Son nueva en Spring y estoy realizando un curso. Más cuando llego a la parte de seguridad me consigo con el siguiente problema. Estoy trabajando con Intellij:

> The injection point has the following annotations:
>       - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>   Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' in your configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception{
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("angular")
                .secret("@angular")
                .scopes("read","write")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(1800)
        .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600*4);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception{
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
                .reuseRefreshTokens(false)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        accessTokenConverter.setSigningKey("algaworks");
        return accessTokenConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }
}
```

Comment: Este es reporitorio... https://github.com/andreindc/algaworks-api/tree/release/2020.04.29/algaworks-api/src/main/java/com/algaworksapi/algaworksapi

Comment: [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52243774/consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-org-springframework-security-authentication-au) hay una pregunta similar, talvez te ayude

Comment: Gracias, ya voy a revisar

Answer (score 1):

Parece que el error se debe a cambios que introdujo Spring Boot 2.0 ([Migration-Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#authenticationmanager-bean)). Se soluciono agregando la siguiente clase

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

Comment: Recuerda aceptar esta respuesta si soluciono tu problema!